# Is it possible for Elastic Search highlighting results to appear in-line instead of in its own tag?

Tags: elasticsearch, highlighting

I have the following query, where I want to highlight all the hits for "China" in-line.  Unfortunately, the results always end up in its own "highlight" tag.   Is there any way to get the results in-line instead of within its own "highlight" section? Thanks!

```
GET /spiderpig/bol/_search
{
  "sort": "_score",
  "from": 0,
  "size": 10,
  "highlight": {
    "number_of_fragments": 0,
    "pre_tags": [
      "<span class='highlight'>"
    ],
    "post_tags": [
      "</span>"
    ],
    "fields": {
      "*": {}
    }
  },
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "China"
    }
  }
}
```

And the results are in its own "highlight" tag which is not desirable.  Is there anyway to get the results inline?

```
"highlight": {
  "PartyShipper.Name": ["DAMCO <span class='highlight'>CHINA</span> SHENZHEN BRANCH"],
  "PartyShipper.Address1": ["12 0112 UNIT 34F GOLDEN BUSINESS CENTER NO 2028 SHENNAN DONG R 51800 SHENZHEN PEOPLES REPUBLIC OF <span class='highlight'>CHINA</span> TEL 075525021558 FAX "]
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "in-line"?

Comment: Highlighting is a different part of the response. As far as I know it is not possible to change that. You can change the amount of words that are highlighted, the tags used, etc.